# Is $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ divisible?

Tags: group-theory, matrices, complex-numbers

A group $G$ (possibly non-abelian) is divisible when for all $k\in \Bbb N$ and $g\in G$ there exists $h\in G$ such that $g=h^k.$ Is the group $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ divisible? Or more precisely, for which $n$ is it divisible? (It clearly is for $n=0$ and $n=1$.)

Comment: When a matrix is diagonalizable, you can find $k$th roots for all $k$. So the question is for left non-diagonalizable matrices.

Comment: The assertion is true for any diagonizable matrix, so you should look at non diagonalizable matrices.

Comment: @Bartek, Instead of changing the original question, why not make a new question? I'll upvote that one, too.

Comment: @Steve OK, but should I ask two new questions or one? The two added questions are probably just as similar to each other as they are to the original question...

Comment: @Bartek, I would make two separate questions---I am not an expert, but it feels to me that most of the complication lies in allowing positive characteristic, and that once this is sorted out, the infinite matrices bit won't be too hard... so maybe just start by asking the same question for an arbitrary a.c. field.

Comment: @Steve OK, I'll do that now and wait with the infinite matrices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The easiest way to see it is to observe that the exponential map sending an arbitrary (not necessarily invertible) matrix $A$ to $e^A$ is onto for $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. (This fails for some of your other favorites matrix groups). Then $$(e^{\frac{1}{n}A})^n=e^A$$  gives you $n$th roots.

Comment: In particular, every *compact* Lie group is divisible.

Comment: @JasonDeVito You should probably throw connected in there.

Comment: @Jason DeVito (with modification suggested by Alex Youcis) Word.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain why the map is onto? I'm not very comfortable manipulating the matrix $\exp.$

Comment: @Alex and Steve:  Yes, of course you are both right.  (I can't be the only person who continually assumes all manifolds are connected, can I?)

Comment: @JasonDeVito Unless you care about dimension $0$ Lie groups--I heard those can be pretty important :)

Comment: @Bartek, Using Jordan decomposition, write an arbitrary invertible matrix as a product $g=s u$ of a semisimple matrix $s$ and a unipotent matrix $u$ that commute with one another. Then take logarithms separately.

Comment: @Steve I haven't heard of the Jordan decomposition before. Could you add a short explanation? (If it's too much trouble, then it's not a problem. I'll read up -- there's a Wikipedia article about it and I see there are references there.)

Comment: @Bartek, It's kind of a long story. Probably wikipedia will sort you out!

Comment: Thank you. I will have to think about this. I'll comment if I have problems.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Can we say that the divisibility of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is being inherited from divisibility of $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @Babak:  There may some sense in which what you're saying is true, but it's not immediately obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The following fact is from to J.J.Rotman and I think you can satisfy it for $G$:

> If $A$ is a group, $m\in\mathbb Z$, and $m_A:~A\to A$ by $$a\longmapsto ma$$ then $A$ is divisible iff $$\forall m\neq 0,~~m_A~~\text{is a surjection}$$