# Is $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ divisible for an algebraically closed field $K?$

Tags: group-theory, matrices, field-theory

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346096/is-mathrmgl-n-mathbb-c-divisible#346098). To reiterate the definition, a group $G$ (possibly non-abelian) is divisible when for all $k\in \Bbb N$ and $g\in G$ there exists $h\in G$ such that $g=h^k.$ Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. For which $n$ is $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ divisible? (It is clearly true for $n=0$ and $n=1$.) The linked question is about the case of $K=\Bbb C$ and the answer is "for all $n$" there.

Comment: You can use the Jordan canonical form to show it is divisible.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat, is it obvious how to take the logarithm of a unipotent matrix in char. $p$? I don't see it at the moment (this is why I suggested asking this question separately).

Comment: @Steve You can do this as follows: find the Jordan canonical form of your matrix, and then replace the diagonal with some $k$-th square roots of the diagonal coefficients (I actually need $k$ not a multiple of $p=\mathrm{car}(K)$). This new matrix may not have $k$-th power equal to the initial matrix, however, its $k$-th power has the same Jordan normal form (here we need $k$ not a multiple of $p$), so it is similar to the initial matrix, and this is enough.

Comment: Nice! You should make that an answer.

Comment: ...and it's a shame more people haven't voted up Geoff's nice observation! Edit: thank you, anonymous upvoters!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

${\rm GL}(n,K)$ is not divisible when $K$ has finite characteristic $p$ and $n >1.$ The maximum order of an element of $p$-power order in ${\rm GL}(n,K)$ is $p^{e+1},$ where $p^{e} < n \leq p^{e+1}$ ($e$ a positive integer). There is an element of that order, and it is not the $p$-th power of any element of ${\rm GL}(n,K).$

Comment: Nice! I suppose you can take something like a unipotent matrix with a single Jordan block for your maximal $p$-power element?

Comment: Thank you. Could you add some proofs and/or references? Just looking at these facts, I'm almost sure I couldn't prove them without at least days of thought. (If I'm wrong and it's actually something simple, please tell me, and I'll try to prove these things.)

Comment: @Bartek, I think it should be straightforward. If $g$ has $p$-power order, then $0=g^q-1=(g-1)^q$ for some power $q$ of $p$, so $g$ differs from $1$ by a nilpotent matrix. The bounds in the answer now come from what the order of nilpotency has to be.

Comment: @Bartek: To make it concrete show that $A=\pmatrix{1&1\cr0&1\cr}$ is not a $p$th power. If $A=B^p$, then the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $B$ must both be $p$th roots  of unity, i.e. equal to $1$. It follows that $(B-I)^p=0$, whence $B^p=I\neq A$.

Comment: @Bartek: Yes, Steve and Jyrki have captured the issue. Take $y$ a unipotent element with a singleJordan block of maximal size $n.$ Then $(y-I)^{n} = 0 \neq (y-I)^{n-1}.$ Then $(y^{p^{e}}- I) = (y-I)^{p^{e}} \neq 0$ and $y^{p^{e+1}}-I = (y-I)^{p^{e+1}} =0.$ Thus $y$ has order $p^{e+1}.$ If $y = z^{p}$ for some $z \in {\rm GL}(n,K),$ then $z$ must be unipotent. But the argument used for $y$ shows that $z$ can't have order greater than $p^{e+1}$ (the fact that $y$ had a single Jordan block was not need to show that $y$ had order at most $p^{e+1}$), a contradiction.